# Unexpected segmentation fault when trying to mix some string

Tags: c

I need to manipulate an string in this way:

If the character is '+' or '-' or '/' or '*', move them to the end of buffer, if not, move to the beginning of the buffer.

My solution is quite simple:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void mix_the_string(char ** buff, char ** string)
{
    printf("The string which will be printed is : %s\n",*string);

    int i = 0;
    int j = strlen(*string) - 1;

    while(i< strlen(*string))
    {
        if(*string[i] != '+' || *string[i] != '-' || *string[i] != '*' || *string[i] != '/')
        {

            printf("in the first if, i = %d, *string[i] = '%d'\n",i,(int)*string[i]);

            *buff[i] = *string[i];
        }
        else
        {
            printf("in the second if, i = %d, *string[i] = '%d'\n",i,(int)*string[i]);
            *buff[j] = *string[i];
        }

        i++;
        j--;
    }
}

int main()
{    
    char * buff  = (char *) malloc(50);
    char * string  = (char *) malloc(50);

    string = "1+2+3";

    mix_the_string(&buff,&string);
    puts(buff);
    free(buff);
    free(string);

    return 0;
}
```

The output of this code is:

```
 The string which will be printed is : 1+2+3
 in the first if, i = 0, *string[i] = '49'
 in the first if, i = 1, *string[i] = '49'
 Segmentation fault
```

I expected with this example that output would be like:

```
The string which will be printed is : 1+2+3
in the first if, i = 0, *string[i] = '49'
in the second if, i = 1, *string[i] = '43'
in the first if, i = 2, *string[i] = '50'
in the second if, i = 3, *string[i] = '43'
in the first if, i = 4, *string[i] = '51'
123++
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: why are you passing the addresses of pointers? this makes it more complex than it should be.

Comment: Which line is causing the crash? Run the code in a debugger and update the question with this vital piece of information

Comment: I think that's not the reason of the problem.

Comment: `int j = strlen(*string) - 1;` if `string` is empty you get `-1`. UB...

Comment: you're decreasing j each time, increasing i each time. maybe you should do that only when storing in the buffer...

Comment: Okay, I changed this, but I still got the problem

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre not entirely UB when `string` is empty as the while loop never happens so `j` is never used

Answer (score 5):

There is difference between `*string[i]` and `(*string)[i]` notation. `[]` has higher precedence than `*` operator. You pass string by pointer to pointer, so you should call `(*string)[i]` in every line of your code.

> `(*string)[i]` means - dereference pointer to array and get `i-th` element of string array

now you are doing

> `*string[i]` - get `i-th` element of string array (!! but this is not array, this is only one element) and dereference first element

Do the same with `buff`.

And in `main` function you should copy *1+2+3* string literal into `string` buffer for example by `strcpy` function.

Comment: Also, in `main()`, `string` is overwritten with `"1+2+3"` and then `free()`ed. Instead, OP should copy `"1+2+3"` into `string`.

Answer (score 0):

There are lot of bugs in your code.

- first `string = "1+2+3";` and then doing `free(string)` is not correct.
  First copy it using `strcpy(string,"1+2+3");` and then
                      `free(string)`
- `string` is double pointer in `mix_the_string()`. Accessing  like `*string[i]` is not correct because `string` is not `array of pointer`. instead of this use `*(*string+i)`. Same applicable for `buf` also.
- finally casting of `malloc` is not required. just `char * buff = malloc(50);` is fine.
- And moreover you don't need to pass `&string` to `mix_the_string()`. just pass `string` thats enough.

Here is the expected code which you want

```
void mix_the_string(char ** buff, char ** string)
{
    printf("The string which will be printed is : %s\n", *string);

    int i = 0;
    int j = strlen(string[0]) - 1;

    while (i < strlen(string[0]))
    {
        if (*(*string + i) != '+' || *(*string + i) != '-' || *(*string + i) != '*' || *(*string + i) != '/')
        {
            printf("in the first if, i = %d, *string[i] = '%d'\n", i, *(*string + i));

            *(*buff + i) = *(*string + i);
        }
        else
        {
            printf("in the second if, i = %d, *string[i] = '%d'\n", i, *(*string + i));
            *(*buff + j) = *(*string + i);
        }
        i++;
        j--;
    }
}

int main()
{
    char * buff = (char *)malloc(50);
    char * string = (char *)malloc(50);

    strcpy(string, "1+2+3");

    mix_the_string(&buff, &string);
    puts(buff);
    free(buff);
    free(string);

    return 0;
}
```